# Django-CMS: PlaceholderField in django admin

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-cms

I'm trying to use PlaceholderField instead of HTMLField in django admin. I read [this](http://docs.django-cms.org/en/develop/how_to/placeholders.html#admin-integration) docs but got nothing
so my `models.py`

```
from django.db import models
from cms.models.fields import PlaceholderField
class Blog(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    field = PlaceholderField('content')
```

Then I added some code to `admin.py`

```
from django.contrib import admin
from example.models import Blog
from cms.admin.placeholderadmin import PlaceholderAdminMixin

class MyModelAdmin(PlaceholderAdminMixin, admin.ModelAdmin):
    pass
admin.site.register(Blog, MyModelAdmin)
```

But when I try to add new model in django admin I
[see only name field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7WA0Z.png)

Is this some steps that I lost?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `PlaceholderField` allows you to add CMS plugins to your blog objects via the front end so you'll only see the `CharField` in an admin view.

In your template for the blog `DetailView` you'll need to render the placeholder field for your object. You'll do something like;

```
{% load cms_tags %}

<h1>{{ object.name }}</h1>

{% render_placeholder object.field "640" %}
```

The docs for the placeholder field are [here](http://docs.django-cms.org/en/develop/how_to/placeholders.html#templates).

Then when you're viewing that `DetailView` you can add content to the placeholder like any standard CMS page with placeholders.

A very good example of a blog system for CMS is aldryn-newsblog, written by the core CMS team. https://github.com/aldryn/aldryn-newsblog

Comment: thanks for example! I've also found some examples in django cms sources. I guess it would help either. much appreciate

Comment: Did you succeed to modify your PlaceholderField with a non admin user? I've tried it even after granting all access in auth permissions and still I get the same message "You don't have permission to modify this plugin"